# Can one 40k army fight another of the same?

Tags: warhammer-40k

My friend is starting a Necron army, and I was going to start a Space Marine army, but Necrons are really an interesting army to play, while the Space Marines are very generic. Could I build a Necron army and fight his Necron army? Is this against the rules?

Comment: If you don't like Space Marines, why not just pick something else? Orks, Eldar, Tyranids..?

Answer (score 15):

There is nothing in the rules to prevent two armies from the same codex from fighting one another.  I would just be sure that you can tell who each model belongs to; this is not too difficult once they are painted, but it could be easy to lose track of who is on which side if there are all just bare plastic.

With the current fluff, Necrons Overlords have their own Dynasties and it is easy to justify a power struggle between two of them.  Most other codexes can have fluff reasons to fight amongst themselves.

Comment: My only question would be about unique characters. I don't know much about necrons, but in a Blood Angel vs Blood Angel match, would both be allowed to have Mephiston? (arbitrary choice of an unique character)

Comment: That would normally be allowed. Characters are only unique within an individual army list; two different players can have the same unique character. Unless players agree to do something different, of course.

Answer (score 7):

Any army can fight against any other army, even Space Marines of the same chapter.

It depends on how much you care about the story of your battles as to how odd this may feel.

If you are just playing games, it won't be an issue. If you want to run a coherent story or campaign then you'll need to justify why the two armies are fighting, and that may be difficult.

Comment: One commander stole the other commander's favorite play thing? If they were Orks it would be super easy to justify.

Comment: An easy one for the entire Imperium: one side has been suspected of being tainted by Chaos. Now you can fight anyone! You still have all of your old enemies, and now even your friends are enemies. (Eldar vs. Eldar might be hard to justify, but add in any Farseer prophecy and it suddenly works just fine. Maybe Tau vs. Tau is harder to justify?)

Comment: @PaulMarshall Tau vs Tau is easy - it'd happen if two Ethereals disagree vehemently enough.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:
If you both want to play with same armies, I don't see what the issue is; **AS LONG** as you know which models belong to who.

If you want to be a player that respects lore, then 2 players might not be able to play the same race v each other (haven't played for a while, but -> Imperials would not fight each other, whereas Orks totally would.) *So Necrons could fight each other and it would make sense.*

Comment: Imperials would fight each other if they believed the other army to be lead by a HERETIC!

Comment: That's true, or if an army had gone corrupt, collaborating with Orks.